# when is it mandatory to use fluent api when defining relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I wonder if it is ever mandatory to use fluent api when defining 1:M, 1:1, and M:M relationships. I know fluent api provides more functionality that data annotations are not able to do. However, if we just think about straight relationships with no additional requirement (e.g., renaming foreign keys in M:M relationships, or CascadeOnDelete, etc.), can we just rely on data annotations ?  Or is it still better to use fluent api for some reasons?

Comment: You don't need the fluent api for the basics. You don't even need annotations if you follow conventions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I like the fluent api because I can then keep my POCOs clean and separate concerns.

Comment: Setting cascade on delete to false and many to many mapping table configurations are two I can think of.

Comment: not sure if you can do composite keys with data annotations either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you can do with `DataAnnotation` you can do with `FluentAPI`, but the opposite is not true. Some features are available only in `FluentAPI`.

**Which should I use?**

Depending on what you are trying to do.

Some relationships can be declared in the class structure. For instance, an n:m relationship can be declared as follows:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
} 

public class Bar
{
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

EF will recognize the n:m: relationship and create the "third table". However, if you want to "choose" the third-table's name, you have to use `FluentAPI`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Bars)
    .WithMany(c => c.Foos)
    .Map(cs =>
        {
            cs.MapLeftKey("FooId");
            cs.MapRightKey("BarId");
            cs.ToTable("FooBarRelationship");
 });
```

`DataAnnotation` are more simple than `FluentAPI`, but if your classes are located in a different assembly, you have to add a reference of `System.Data.ComponentModel`, what it is not nice.

`FluentAPI` seems complicated, but it can do everything that `DataAnnotation` can do, and even more. In addition, you can use it outside of the class without problems. Particularly, I prefer `FluentAPI`, because it seems more clean and organised.

Futhermore, if you choose `DataAnnotation`, keep in mind that you might have to use `FluentAPI` as well. So, if you want to use only one approach, you must choose `FluentAPI`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of both. Personally I prefer the Data Annotations because it seems simpler to me to set them up while you're writing out the class. It's also easier to reference later since it's contained there. As you said, sometimes you need to modify something using fluent api, but if you don't need it, it's less typing to use data annotations.

In fact, if you're doing simple relationships, you don't even need to explicitly use data annotations most of the time, as EF can infer relationships based on keys and naming conventions.